# Solr many to many self join relatiohship with reverse relationship

Tags: solr, many-to-many, schema, data-modeling, self-join

I have millions of court opinions that I want to index. In our relational database, each opinion cites to on average about 30 other opinions, using a self-join  to say A cites B, B cites C, etc. In the database, these can be queried in either direction. So you can say:

> Which opinions does this opinion cite?

Or:

> Which opinions is this one cited by?

The average number of both is identical, since one is the reverse of the other. But the range varies considerably. In the first case, most opinions top out around 100 outward citations to other opinions and average around 30.

In the second case, [some opinions have nearly 30,000 inbound citations](https://www.courtlistener.com/?q=&order_by=citeCount+desc&stat_Precedential=on), because they've been cited many, many times. (And this number grows by the day!)

What I need to do is index the items so that they can be queried either with:

```
cited_by:23
```

(about 30 results, usually, max of 100 or so.)

Or:

```
cites:23
```

(0 to about 30,000 results)

I'm pretty sure I need to use a multi-value field for this. But my questions are:

1. I only want to index this from the `cites` direction. That is, I don't want to be pulling 30k items from my database to index a single item, and I don't want to be updating that item every time it's cited anew, which happens many times daily.
2. I'd like to be able to query this in either direction. In fact, it's more useful to be able to query `cited_by` than it is to query `cites`, beacuse getting a list of recent citations ***to*** an opinion is pretty incredible.
3. Are there any tricks to know when making a self-join in Solr? I guess it doesn't even know about the concept?

Answer (score 1):

Solr isn't really well suited for joins (as you mention), but there's alternative ways of solving something like this. While pulling 30k rows to index a single item might be extensive, you can use the [Atomic Updates support to add single values to multi-valued fields](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents) as the citations arrive. That being said - 30k values in a multi valued field is on the larger side, so you'll have to just test to see any performance issues that could arise (since the rest of the index will affect that as well).

A different strategy is to have a single collection where each "document" is a [cites, cited_by, date] set. You can then query this collection by itself to get any references that has been cited/cites a different opinion, and query the main core for the actual references.

As long as the collections live on the same server, you can join between the cores - if you only need the values from one of them (meaning that all the values Solr return has to live in the same core, Solr does not perform joins where it fetched values from both sides of the join).

Comment: Nice. I think the atomic updates could be a good technique, but I've been talking to co-workers and they say that I should just keep the `cites` data in Solr, and use it to go both directions. I haven't played with multi-value fields, but apparently it'll be possible to do a `cites:23`-type query (0 to 30,000 results), and I can just get the value of the `cites` field to get the other direction (0 to 100 results).